# Simple Yahoo Pipe not working

Tags: rss, yahoo-pipes, feedparser

All I want to do is mix three RSS feeds into one, remove duplicates (based on the title) and sort the items by date of publish. So I built this pipe (http://pipes.yahoo.com/nerdvanagr/olympiacosbc) which is just refusing to work: As you can see, for example, the 4th and the 7th item have almost exactly the same title so one of them shouldn't appear. Any ideas on what might be wrong?

**EDIT:** The general problem is stability, sometimes it works, some other it doesn't...

Comment: looks liking it's working fine to me... Can you clarify the error?

Comment: Yeah, I guess I have to if I really want some help.. :D

Answer (score 0):

Just use `item.title` for unique and `item.pubDate` for the sort and you'll be fine.